Bean 'cacheConfiguration' of type is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors
Why does this file generate this warning and how do I fix it?

WARN 35416 --- [           main]
trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'cacheConfiguration'
of type [xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.CacheConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not
eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example:
not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected
into a currently created BeanPostProcessor
[meterRegistryPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding
BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.

@Configuration
public class CacheConfiguration implements CachingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return new CustomCacheErrorHandler();
    }
}

I have read about @Lazy but don´t know how to apply that to my file.

It doesn't need to be an @Configuration but a regular @Component that could remove the warning. However the warning is more informational as the CachingConfigurer is created very early in the process before beanpostprocessing will even take place (as it is still being setup).

I get the same error if I change '@Configuration' to '@Component'.

It is not an error it is information and it doesn't matter in this case as I explained (apparently you stopped reading after the first sentence).

:D Sorry, I get the same warning.

Please read, and don't stop after the first sentence. It doesn't matter for this specific case.
